# Find out next most close date from NSDate array of times

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can I find out the next prayer from the array of times, I have total 6 Prayers at different times and i want to compare each one with current time and have to find out which one is most near as a next prayer, Date format also creating problems because it give always in UTC format and I have to use local time zone, I am using the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTimeIntervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *intervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *arrayPrayers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 1",@"time":@"1:12 am"}];
[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 2",@"time":@"5:45 am"}];
[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 3",@"time":@"12:03 pm"}];
[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 4",@"time":@"3:30 pm"}];
[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 4",@"time":@"6:20 pm"}];
[arrayPrayers addObject:@{@"prayer":@"prayer 6",@"time":@"7:50 pm"}];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrayPrayers.count];
for (NSDictionary *timeDict in arrayPrayers)
{
    NSString *timeString = [timeDict objectForKey:@"time"];
    NSString *name = [timeDict objectForKey:@"prayer"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
    [dates addObject:@{@"prayer":name,@"time":timeString, @"date":date}];
}


for (int i =0 ; i<arrayPrayers.count; i++) {


    NSDictionary *timeDict = arrayPrayers[i];
    NSString *timeString = [timeDict objectForKey:@"time"];
    //NSString *name = [timeDict objectForKey:@"prayer"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];

    NSComparisonResult result = [[NSDate date] compare:date];
    if(result==NSOrderedAscending){
        NSLog(@"next prayer");
    }else if(result==NSOrderedDescending){
        NSLog(@"last prayer");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"current prayer");
    }

    if ([date earlierDate:[NSDate date]]) {
        NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = @{@"Prayer":timeDict,
                                   @"Time":timeString,
                                   @"Index":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i],
                                   @"Interval":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",interval]};
        [arrayTimeIntervals addObject:tempDict];
        [intervals addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",interval]];
    }
}

NSNumber * min = [intervals valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"];

NSUInteger index = 0;
for(int i =0 ; i<intervals.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary* dict = arrayTimeIntervals[i];
    if([[dict objectForKey:@"Interval"] intValue] == [min intValue]) {
        index = i;
        NSLog(@"next prayer is!!!:%ld",index);
        break;
    }
}

NSDictionary *dict = [arrayTimeIntervals objectAtIndex:index];
NSLog(@"next prayer object is:%@",dict);
```

Comment: @Josh Caswell, the question you're reffered doesn't have accepted answer.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes, and I also tried but not solved my problem with that.

Comment: your dateFromString returning wrong date, i mean wrong Year.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati it will be updated by server daily so we need to care about hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: NO no no , just NSLog the NSDate(from string),it be like 1999-12-31 01:12:00 +0000!  the date returning is not current date!

Comment: i will suggest you not to pass only "time" also pass full date!

Comment: @Nitin Gohel: This question _is_ a duplicate of [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591089/calculate-nearest-time-from-array-with-current-time?lq=1); they have exactly the same problem. Why did you reopen it?

Comment: As u can see the duplicated question that u added have no accepted answer so I reopen it

Comment: @NitinGohel Not having an accepted answer has nothing to do with duplicates, and in this case, the asker of that question has posted his own answer, which has been upvoted.

Comment: I feel that this question bit different and might some one can answer with letest ios so I reopen it. If u feel this is not relevant then close again

Comment: @NitinGohel and josh-caswell, Guys will you please answer my question instead of having reopen and close argue?

Comment: The answer is at the linked question, @Arpit; that's why I provided the link.